# Using Python's C API, what is an efficient way to pass large amounts of data?

Tags: python, c

I've been exploring the C API that Python offers.

https://docs.python.org/3.11/c-api/index.html

It's easy enough to move primitive data (double, long, int) from C into Python using things like:

PyObject *PyLong_FromLong(long v)

Building a Python list object and passing it primitives is also reasonable to do.

I was hoping to find a way to pass data in bulk. I know I can create 1,000,000 PyObject's out of doubles and add them each to a list, but it seems like there should be a better way. I think the Buffer Protocol is likely the way to go, but there isn't much in the way of examples.

https://docs.python.org/3.11/c-api/buffer.html

Whether the data is pushed into a Python list, array or numpy array doesn't really matter, it would just be nice to avoid millions of calls from C into Python.

Thanks!

Comment: If you've got big arrays of primitives or POD structs, numpy arrays are probably the way to go.

Comment: Any ideas on how? I do suspect that numpy arrays are the most memory and time efficient to work with in this context, I just can figure out what C API calls are required.

Comment: For primitive arrays, it looks like `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` should work (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData). I'm not sure about arrays of structs, but I got more relevant results by searching with "recarray" instead of "structured array".